# git -- locking master branch for some users?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I would like to force other team-members to not work on the master-branch but on a development branch. we have a central git-repository where we push our work into. i would like to know if it's possible to block users from pushing changes to the master-branch but only allow certain users to do so.

I would like to have the following "workflow"

- development is always only done with a development-branch
- the release-manager is responsible for the master branch and only he is allowed to merge stuff from a development branch into the master and push it to the master-branch on the central repository to.

Is this possible and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Access control is outsourced from git to the operating system running the server. If you're running your own server, I'd recommend installing gitosis: http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way

Comment: thanks, i'll have a look at gitosis ...

Comment: I thought that it is exactly because `git` is distributed, you don't need to control permissions because no 'shared' repository exists? In other words, any team member working on the project will work on their own copy of the repository, and it's the maintainer that merges branches into a 'master' repository (just a name for it, not to be confused with master branch.)

Comment: yes, maybe i am still to much into centralized thinking (coming from cvs and svn), but: we have a central repository where every developer can pull from, to get for example the master branch. but i don't want them to push. i think this could be handled different by adding a third repository where only release-manager has access to, but i thought the other way would be more easy to maintain ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`man githooks`](http://schacon.github.com/git/githooks.html): In the shared repo, you can create a `$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/hooks/pre-receive` or `$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/hooks/update` script that verifies what your users are trying to push to which refs.  Git comes with a [update-paranoid](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=contrib/hooks/update-paranoid;hb=HEAD) example hook enforcing per-ref ACLs.

Comment: thanks ... the githooks seem to be very powerful. i'll have a look at both gitosis and githooks

Comment: Can someone expand on this?  I looked at the `[update-paranoid](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/hooks/update-paranoid?id=HEAD)` hook, but I'm not sure I understand what the ACL would look like for multiple users.  Is it expected that a user would have multiple entries for allowed committers in the form : `committer = John Doe <john.doe@example.com>`, and this could be used for N users like : `
committer = John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
committer = User2 <user2@example.com>
committer = User3 <user3@example.com>`

 ?

Comment: @b.long: `update-paranoid` expects one `users/${USER}.acl` within the `/vcs/acls.git` repo (not *this* repo) for each SSH login; within each, there can be as many `committer =` lines as desired.  But you'll probably want to modify or rewrite the script for your own use.

Comment: @ephemient , I see.  So, ${USER} in this case is the `git` user (the user that own's the repository), right?  Are you saying this hook isn't necessarily meant for general purpose use?  I was looking for something generic, that would simply allow me to enumerate the users who could commit on the master branch (e.g. git flow), while other branches would retain default configuration.

Comment: @b.long Suppose there is a setup where I push to `me@remote:/srv/git/repo.git` and you push to `you@remote:/srv/git/repo.git` (this is possible with the right permissions and umask even if the repo is owned by somebody else).  Then this hook would check with `me.acl` when I push and `you.acl` when you push.  If everybody pushes as `common@remote`, then everyone can impersonate anybody else in their commits.  This script probably doesn't work out-of-the-box for you (example, it has hard-coded paths) but you can use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

My low level approach would simply be to let the RM be the only one with SSH keys to push to the repository everyone else use as the master baseline. That way, nobody but the RM can push to master - yet everybody can work since they have their own local development branches and devs can share among themselves the branches they like.

The next step is to make a cooking pot tester for the things that will go into master soon. This pot is normally called `next` or `dev`. The idea is, that the more impact a branch has, the longer it cooks before a merge to master. This gives the RM full control over what branches should graduate and still gives everyone a heads-up.

Comment: thanks. i thought about ssh, too and it would be quite easy to setup. but i thought there should be 'better' ways ... ?